# Cropping multiple parts from the single image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, crop

I want to crop multiple parts from the image to make groudtruth using mouse pointer. There are different number of objects in each so I can't run `for` loop for specific number of times. However, I can use `while` loop. But how can I stop that?

```
for i=1:10

    [tt bb]=imcrop(img);
    crop.img{i,:}=tt;
    crop.bb(i,:)=bb;
end
```

Comment: please show how you have attempted to answer this

Comment: @Raha I have updated with the code. Again its using the `for` loop. I want to use `while` or something different that can be stop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [`if`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) condition with [`waitforbuttonpress`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitforbuttonpress.html) for this. When you're done cropping an image portion and want to crop another portion, click any mouse button and the loop will continue. When you don't want to crop any other portion, press any keyboard button and the loop will [`break`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html).

Demo Code:

```
img = imread('peppers.png');
f = figure;
k = 1;
while 1
    [tt, bb] = imcrop(img);
    crop.img{k,:} = tt;
    crop.bb{k,:} = bb;
    if waitforbuttonpress
        break;
    end
    k = k+1;
end
```

Note that it requires your figure window to be in focus.

Answer (score 4):

How about just pressing Esc when you want to quit?

```
img = imread('peppers.png');

k = 1;
f = figure;
imshow(img)
while true
    title('Double click to select next area, press Esc when finished')
    [tt, bb] = imcrop(f);
    if isempty(tt)
        close(f)
        break
    end
    crop.img{k,:} = tt;
    crop.bb{k,:} = bb;
    k = k+1;
end
```